ClassCastException in Hibernate with BasicTypeImpl and BasicPluralType
I'm encountering a ClassCastException while working with Hibernate in my Java project. The error occurs when Hibernate attempts to cast an instance of BasicTypeImpl to BasicPluralType. Here is the stack trace snippet:
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.hibernate.type.internal.BasicTypeImpl cannot be cast to class org.hibernate.type.BasicPluralType (org.hibernate.type.internal.BasicTypeImpl and org.hibernate.type.BasicPluralType are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:607) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.hibernate.type.internal.BasicTypeImpl cannot be cast to class org.hibernate.type.BasicPluralType (org.hibernate.type.internal.BasicTypeImpl and org.hibernate.type.BasicPluralType are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1806) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:600) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
Caused by: jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.hibernate.type.internal.BasicTypeImpl cannot be cast to class org.hibernate.type.BasicPluralType (org.hibernate.type.internal.BasicTypeImpl and org.hibernate.type.BasicPluralType are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:421) ~[spring-orm-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:366) ~[spring-orm-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1853) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.hibernate.type.internal.BasicTypeImpl cannot be cast to class org.hibernate.type.BasicPluralType (org.hibernate.type.internal.BasicTypeImpl and org.hibernate.type.BasicPluralType are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.internal.ArrayDdlTypeImpl.getCastTypeName(ArrayDdlTypeImpl.java:34) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.ast.spi.AbstractSqlAstTranslator.getCastTypeName(AbstractSqlAstTranslator.java:6992) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.ast.spi.AbstractSqlAstTranslator.visitCastTarget(AbstractSqlAstTranslator.java:6939) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.ast.tree.expression.CastTarget.accept(CastTarget.java:80) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.ast.spi.AbstractSqlAstTranslator.render(AbstractSqlAstTranslator.java:7073) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.produce.function.internal.PatternRenderer.render(PatternRenderer.java:224) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.produce.function.internal.PatternRenderer.render(PatternRenderer.java:159) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.produce.function.internal.PatternRenderer.render(PatternRenderer.java:142) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.dialect.function.CastFunction.render(CastFunction.java:76) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.ast.spi.AbstractSqlAstTranslator.renderCasted(AbstractSqlAstTranslator.java:5813) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.dialect.SqlAstTranslatorWithMerge.renderMergeUsingQuerySelection(SqlAstTranslatorWithMerge.java:161) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.dialect.SqlAstTranslatorWithMerge.renderMergeUsingQuery(SqlAstTranslatorWithMerge.java:150) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.dialect.SqlAstTranslatorWithMerge.renderMergeUsing(SqlAstTranslatorWithMerge.java:126) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.dialect.SqlAstTranslatorWithMerge.renderMergeStatement(SqlAstTranslatorWithMerge.java:82) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.dialect.SqlAstTranslatorWithMerge.createMergeOperation(SqlAstTranslatorWithMerge.java:43) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect.usingMerge(PostgreSQLDialect.java:1529) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect.createOptionalTableUpdateOperation(PostgreSQLDialect.java:1521) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.model.internal.OptionalTableUpdate.createMutationOperation(OptionalTableUpdate.java:144) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.mutation.AbstractMutationCoordinator.createOperationGroup(AbstractMutationCoordinator.java:87) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.mutation.UpdateCoordinatorStandard.buildStaticUpdateGroup(UpdateCoordinatorStandard.java:1663) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.mutation.UpdateCoordinatorStandard.<init>(UpdateCoordinatorStandard.java:93) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.mutation.MergeCoordinator.<init>(MergeCoordinator.java:23) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.buildMergeCoordinator(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3658) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.doLateInit(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3404) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.postInstantiate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3690) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.finishInitialization(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:202) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.initializeMappingModel(SessionFactoryImpl.java:371) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:300) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:457) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1506) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:75) ~[spring-orm-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) ~[spring-orm-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    ... 215 common frames omitted

Here are the dependencies in my pom.xml file
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <keycloak.version>25.0.1</keycloak.version>
        <spring-addons.version>7.8.4</spring-addons.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-pulsar</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-quartz</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-envers</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
            <version>6.5.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-database-postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc11</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-testcontainers</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>pulsar</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>com.c4-soft.springaddons</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-addons-starter-oidc</artifactId>
           <version>${spring-addons.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
            <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
            <classifier>jakarta</classifier>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
            <classifier>jakarta</classifier>
            <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0.Beta1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>s3</artifactId>
            <version>2.21.46</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-admin-client</artifactId>
            <version>${keycloak.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
            <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
            <version>8.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.750</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.twilio.sdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>twilio</artifactId>
            <version>8.26.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.cloudinary</groupId>
            <artifactId>cloudinary-taglib</artifactId>
            <version>1.39.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.cloudinary</groupId>
            <artifactId>cloudinary-http44</artifactId>
            <version>1.39.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>am.ik.spring</groupId>
            <artifactId>retryable-client-http-request-interceptor</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
<build>
        <finalName>${project.name}-${project.version}</finalName>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
                            <processor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.11.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>1.6.0.Beta1</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
                            <version>0.2.0</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <compilerArg>
                            -Amapstruct.defaultComponentModel=spring
                        </compilerArg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

What I've Tried:
Ensured that all Hibernate dependencies are on the same version.
Reviewed my entity mappings for potential issues.
Checked my Hibernate and database configurations.
Questions:
Has anyone encountered a similar issue with BasicTypeImpl and BasicPluralType?
Are there any specific configurations or dependencies I should look into?
Any tips on debugging or resolving this type of ClassCastException?
I could have pasted the whole entities in the application, but they are actually plenty, and I don't know which part of the code is actually causing the error
But this is the base class where all entities inherit from
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners(Auditable.class)
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@SoftDelete(strategy = SoftDeleteType.DELETED, converter = TrueFalseConverter.class)
@SuperBuilder
@NoArgsConstructor
public class VegeelAuditableModel implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    Long id;

    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)

    String publicId;

    @TenantId
    String companyId;

    String companyName;

    @CreatedDate
    LocalDateTime createdDate;

    @LastModifiedDate
    LocalDateTime lastModifiedDate;

    @CreatedBy
    @Builder.Default
    String createdBy = "SYSTEM";

    Boolean dirty = Boolean.FALSE;

    Boolean approved = Boolean.FALSE;
    @LastModifiedBy
    String lastModifiedBy;

    @PrePersist
    public void generatePublicId() {
        this.publicId = VegeelUtilGenerator.generateId();
//        this.companyId = TenantContext.getTenantId();
        this.companyName = TenantContext.getTenantName();
    }
}

This seems similar to this in the hibernate discourse site but that didn't seem to help me.

I don't think you need the hibernate-envers dependency, that is already pulled in with spring-data-envers. Ditch hibernate-validator that is included with spring-boot-starter-validation already. Don't use @Data with entities (see this blog of mine on why https://deinum.biz/2019-02-13-Lombok-Data-Ojects-Arent-Entities/). Please post the full stacktrace and not just a snippet. Judging from the snippet I think it fails on some query validation.

here is the full stack trace

I have edited the question with the whole stack trace, also I have removed every unnecessary dependency, I have replaced @Data with @Setter and @Getter, and I am leaving out ToString for now, as it is not needed for now, but I am still stuck with the error,

The error comes from a wrong declaration (or missing) on a collection. Hence it isn't part of this mapped supperclass but one of your actual entities.

There can be issue with your entity mappings or configurations. This problem arise due to incompatible Hibernate versions or misconfigurations.
If you are using Hibernate-envers version 6.5.2.Final. Make sure your other Hibernate dependencies match this version or the recommended compatible versions.
Enable debug logging for Hibernate to get details into what might be causing the issue.
Add these properties :
logging.level.org.hibernate=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type=TRACE


I have removed the explicit declaration of the hibernate envers, because it is being pulled in as a transitive dependency by spring data envers, also the hibernate version is 6.5.2.Final
the spring data envers version is 3.3.2.
But the error has not gone

Test with a Clean Setup : Start with spring-boot-starter-data-jpa and its dependencies, and add others one by one.
